# Value counts per period, taking prior values into account

Tags: pandas

We have a list of records that indicate status changes for a specified item. So, each record indicates the item, its active status (0 or 1) as well as the date when that status was changed.

Small example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
    {"item": "A", "active": 1, "date": "2016-01-01"},
    {"item": "B", "active": 1, "date": "2016-02-01"},
    {"item": "C", "active": 0, "date": "2016-02-10"},
    {"item": "B", "active": 0, "date": "2016-03-01"},
    {"item": "A", "active": 0, "date": "2016-04-01"},
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#    active        date item
# 0       1  2016-01-01    A
# 1       1  2016-02-01    B
# 2       0  2016-02-10    C
# 3       0  2016-03-01    B
# 4       0  2016-04-01    A
```

I would like to compute an aggregation to indicate the number of active items that existed per time period. The number should include those items, whose status has not changed (in the example, A is not mentioned for February or March, but it should be counted in both). So in the above example, this would be a correct result:

```
month   active_count
--------------------
2016-01 1
2016-02 2
2016-03 1
2016-04 0
```

How do we include the most recent value of an item in the calculation of a period's count?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- convert column `date` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) + [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) for `month` period
- [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) + upsample by [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.ffill.html)
- `groupby` by `Datetimeindex` level of `MultiIndex` + [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html)
- last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.to_period('M')
df1 = df.set_index('date')
        .groupby('item')
        .resample('M')
        .ffill()
        .groupby(level=1)['active']
        .sum()
        .reset_index(name='active_count')

print (df1)
     date  active_count
0 2016-01             1
1 2016-02             2
2 2016-03             1
3 2016-04             0
```

Comment: This does not appear to be working correctly. If I changed the sample data to this: `data = [{"item": "A", "active": 1, "date": "2016-01-01"}, {"item": "B", "active": 1, "date": "2016-02-01"}, {"item": "C", "active": 1, "date": "2016-02-10"}, {"item": "B", "active": 0, "date": "2016-03-01"}, {"item": "A", "active": 0, "date": "2016-04-01"}]`, then the `active_count` for `2016-2` and `2016-03` should be `3` and `2`, respectively. The above code however yields `3` and `1` for those periods.